# iOS - AVAudioSession : isInputAvailable Notification not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, delegates, avaudiosession

I could see that the delegate methods for AVAudioSession are deprecated. So I decided to implement notification handlers for AVAudioSession notifications. I was able to handle changes in isInputAvailable property through delegates previously. I don't seem to find any notifications available for changes in this property. How do I implement this?